# How do I get the user uid from firebase after the user logs in and gets transferred to another page

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to retrieve the ownername from my table in the firebase realtime database but I am having trouble with retrieving the appropriate user uid.

[Here is a screenshot of my database but below is a text representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRl3k.jpg)

customer_account

- 0QTHF03MirUmhWmhwTqIAbdWmLX2

  - ownername
- LySvRKuUgnMIWhyHPruHaINGIAY2

  - ownername

I need to associate the uid to the appropriate user so I can retrieve their data and display it in the page. This script will be used in the dashboard after the user logs in.

I have tried following tutorials on YouTube but the tutorials they have is for one page website. I have tried manually retrieving a user uid by changing it to the actual user uid in the database and the code works. I think I am having trouble finding the right syntax to do what I need to do.

[I did it this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37XYK.jpg) [and here is the console.log screenshot that showed it worked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Amdm.jpg)

Here is my script code. I only know some vanilla javascript

```
<script type="module">
     // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-analytics.js";
    import { getDatabase, ref, onValue } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-database.js";
    import { getAuth } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-auth.js";

    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "[REDACTED]",
        authDomain: "[REDACTED]",
        databaseURL: "[REDACTED]",
        projectId: "[REDACTED]",
        storageBucket: "[REDACTED]",
        messagingSenderId: "[REDACTED]",
        appId: "[REDACTED]",
        measurementId: "[REDACTED]"
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
    const database = getDatabase(app);
    const auth = getAuth();
    //const user = userCredential.user;

    console.log("Test");
    //Code that I am trying to do
    const userDetails = ref(database, 'customer_account/' + user.uid + '/ownername');
    onValue(userDetails, (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        const ownername = data;
        document.getElementById("welcomename").innerHTML = "Welcome, "+ ownername + "!";
        console.log("Owner name: " + ownername);
        console.log("Owner name retrieved.");
    });

    //Code that works but I hardcoded which user.uid gets read from the database
    /*
    const userDetails = ref(database, 'customer_account/0QTHF03MirUmhWmhwTqIAbdWmLX2/ownername');
    onValue(userDetails, (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        const ownername = data;
        console.log(ownername);
        console.log("Owner name retrieved.");
    });
    */
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while but I found out eventually. I needed to use onAuthStateChanged from firebase auth to be able to access the uid.

Here's the updated code. I have changed the variable name from userDetails to getUserData but it still functions the same.

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-app.js";
        import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-analytics.js";
        import { getDatabase, ref, onValue } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-database.js";
        import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-auth.js";

        // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "[REDACTED]",
            authDomain: "[REDACTED]",
            databaseURL: "[REDACTED]",
            projectId: "[REDACTED]",
            storageBucket: "[REDACTED]",
            messagingSenderId: "[REDACTED]",
            appId: "[REDACTED]",
            measurementId: "[REDACTED]"
        };

        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
        const database = getDatabase(app);
        const auth = getAuth(app);

        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            if (user) {
                // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
                // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
                const getUserData = ref(database, 'customer_account/' + user.uid);
                onValue(getUserData, (snapshot) => {
                    const data = snapshot.val();
                    const ownername = data.ownername;
                    document.getElementById("welcomename").innerHTML = "Welcome, " + ownername + "!";
                })
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                // ...
            }
        });
```

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out @ratatatat! . ---- Going forward, this is also the first code snippet in the Firebase documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yeah it is but I thought it is only to check if the user is signed in or not so I did not include it at first. For me, the firebase document is confusing because it doesn't explain what the variables in the code snippet is supposed to do. It gets easy once you get the ball rolling though.